# Download file on row click, in extjs4

Tags: extjs4, gridpanel, extjs4.2

i have a grid panel with a column that if you click you downalod a file associate to this row.
In extjs 2 i just define a new renderer that is a function who return only return the String format of an url like this:

```
function DownaloadFile(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store)
if (record.data.id){

     return String.format('<b><a href="<c:url value='/fileDownload.action?id={0}'/>" title="<fmt:message key='button.table.file.download.tooltip'/>"><img src="<c:url value="/icons/icon_download.gif"/>"/></a></b>',record.data.id);
}
```

This syntax is not rigth in ExtJS4.2 because String.format is now Ext.String.format but when i made this change nothig happens.

I try to use the new actioncolumn in the column definition in this way:

```
{
                        xtype:'actioncolumn',
                        text: "download", 
                        width:80,
                        items: [{
                                sortable: false, 
                                align:'center',
                                iconCls: 'download_icon',
                                hrefTarget: '_blank',
                                handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                                    var rec = reportPanel.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                                    return Ext.String.format('<b><a href="<c:url value='/fileDownload.action?id={0}'/>" title="download.tooltip"></a></b>',rec.id);
                                }
                        }]
                }
```

but something is wrong because javascript debugger doesn't made any type of error.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `handler` property of `actioncolumn` (witch renders an icon, or a series of icons in a grid cell, and offers a scoped click handler for each icon) is documented as:

> A function called when the icon is clicked.

Consider using the [`templatecolumn`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Template) (witch renders a value by processing a Model's data using a configured XTemplate) instead and passing it a `tpl` property.